# easy way to switch a signal

Tags: switches, relay, multiplexer

I have below configuration:

```
                |---------|------- LED1
                |         |
24V, 350mA------|Switcher |------- LED2
                |         |
                |---------|------- LED3
                      |
                      | 
                      |
                MCU to select the line
```

I need to route the input (24V, 350mA) to one of LED string at the output (1,2,3) by a MCU to turn on/off the LEDs. It is required that all LEDs may be turned on at the same time. ( I can dedicated a GPIO per led string on/off)

What is best to use as a switcher considering 1) small size 2) low cost? It should have long product life (>10 years). I couldn't decide if I should prepare something with 3 transistors and each transistor is controlled by a MCU or a signal relay or a multiplexer.. What would you be your suggestion?

Comment: There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. Much better than ASCII-art!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For small size and low cost, MOSFETs are the way to go. 3 MOSFETs, 3 GPIO lines, simple.

Relays are bulky and may not have the lifetime you want, and a multiplexer doesn't work very well because of the power requirements and because you want them all on at the same time.

Comment: why mosfet? is it because of power consumption?

Comment: @sven MOSFETs dissipate a little less power and require 1 resistor less than a bipolar transistors.

Answer (score 1):

I would use 3 transistors. A relay is not good from size or life time consideration. A multiplexer is a set of switches, usually transistors. A SI2308BDS in SOT23 case size would be suitable.